# Kubeflow Kale specify container image in pipeline step

Tags: docker, kubeflow, kubeflow-pipelines, kubeflow-kale, kale

Kale allows user to specify only `step` and `dependency` from the UI. However, I would like to also specify the docker image to use for the step.

I can't figure how to specify a custom docker image to use in the pipeline step from Kale UI.

Any suggestions on how to implement this?

Answer (score 1):

Specifying an image per step in Kale is not currently possible. This is a feature the Kale team is presently working on. Stay tuned!